# TensorFlow Probability (tfp) equivalent of np.quantile()

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to find a TensorFlow equivalent of [`np.quantile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html). I have found [`tfp.stats.quantiles()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/quantiles) (`tfp` stands for TensorFlow Probability). However, its constructs are a bit different from that of `np.quantile()`.

Consider the following example:

```py
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

inputs = tf.random.normal((1, 4096, 4))

print("NumPy")
print(np.quantile(inputs.numpy(), q=0.9, axis=1, keepdims=False))
```

I am not sure from the TFP docs how I could write the above using `tfp.stats.quantile()`. I tried checking out the source code of both methods, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to be more helpful here than [I was on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/864#issuecomment-1416956051).

There is a difference in behavior between `np.quantile` and `tfp.stats.quantiles`. The key difference here is that `numpy.quantile` will

> Compute the q-th quantile of the data along the specified axis.

where `q` is the

> Quantile or sequence of quantiles to compute, which must be between 0 and 1 inclusive.

and `tfp.stats.quantiles`

> Given a vector `x` of samples, this function estimates the cut points by returning `num_quantiles + 1` cut points

So you need to tell `tfp.stats.quantiles` how many quantiles you want and then select out the `q`th quantile. If it isn't clear how to do this just from the API, if you look at the [source for `tfp.stats.quantiles`](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/0759c57eb0306a5bb0fcc3d105bbcab9943092a5/tensorflow_probability/python/stats/quantiles.py#L727-L741) (for `v0.19.0`) we can see that it shows us how we can get a similar return structure as NumPy.

For completeness, setting up a virtual environment with

```
$ cat requirements.txt
numpy==1.24.2
tensorflow==2.11.0
tensorflow-probability==0.19.0
```

allows us to run

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

inputs = tf.random.normal((1, 4096, 4), dtype=tf.float64)
q = 0.9

numpy_quantiles = np.quantile(inputs.numpy(), q=q, axis=1, keepdims=False)

tfp_quantiles = tfp.stats.quantiles(
    inputs, num_quantiles=100, axis=1, interpolation="linear"
)[int(q * 100)]

assert np.allclose(numpy_quantiles, tfp_quantiles.numpy())

print(f"{numpy_quantiles=}")
# numpy_quantiles=array([[1.31727661, 1.2699167 , 1.28735237, 1.27137588]])
print(f"{tfp_quantiles=}")
# tfp_quantiles=<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 4), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[1.31727661, 1.2699167 , 1.28735237, 1.27137588]])>
```

Comment: Thanks much! It was indeed unclear from the API to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `tfp.stats.percentile(inputs, 90., axis=1, keepdims=False)` -- the only difference from quantile is the `90.` replacing `.90`.